# determine the stability of an equilibrium point(x,0).

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, stability-theory

I would like to determine the stability of equilibrium point $(x,0)$ of the differential equation

$\dot x = Ax$

$ A= 
\bigg[
\begin{matrix}
0&0\\0&a 
\end{matrix}
\bigg]
$ and $  a >0 $

I got 
$ x'(t) = 0\ $
$\ y'(t) = a*y$

So, the equilibrium point is $(x,0)$.

How can I determine the stability of these equilibrium points?

[Here is the phase portrait:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnj1j.png)

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The entire $x$ axis is an equilibrium point.

Comment: @Moo I draw the phase portrait, and I think the equilibrium point is unstable.

Comment: Thanks! Please add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to determine the stability of the equilibrium points of the system $\dot x = Ax$, where

$$ A= 
\bigg[
\begin{matrix}
0&0\\0&a 
\end{matrix}
\bigg], ~\text{with}~a >0 $$

The critical points are where we simultaneously have $x' = y' = 0$ and we get the entire $x-$axis as

$$(x, y) = (x, 0)$$

Since this system is decoupled, we can write 
$$\begin{align} x'(t) &= 0 \implies x(t) = c \\  y'(t) &= ay \implies y(t) = c e^{a t} \end{align}$$

The phase portrait is

[image]

Using all of the information above, we determine that the critical point is unstable.